# Is there an Application.DoEvents equivalent for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ActiveMail with an attachment.  I need to pause long enough for the attachment to be generated before continuing processing.  I could put the call in a !exists loop but I was wondering if there was a DoEvents equivalent.

For clarification.  DoEvents is a method that allows the system to catch up all the processing going on in the background before continuing to the next statement in the code.  Some have suggested using Sleep(xx) which works but either wastes time or does not wait long enough for the system to catch up. :)

Comment: I don't know what the heck DoEvents is, but generally this type of behavior is implemented in a background job using Sidekiq or Resque.

Comment: I do use background processing for sending emails and such.  But I still need the DoEvents in those processes.

Comment: Why can't your background job generate the attachment synchronously and then send the email? There's no "DoEvents" concept in Ruby.

Comment: What I need is for my background job to wait until the attachment is finished and correctly attached and the body of the email is filled out before sending it.  That is the problem.  It is being sent before it is ready.